# Why is Chrome/Chromium missing the Downloads Icon?

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, chromium

I've had this issue with Chrome and Chromium for some time, thinking it was due to the fact that iconset I'm using is missing some Icons , but I've tried with many different sets and apparently none have the the correct Icon.

Is it Chrome/Chromium that is expecting another icon? (and what would it's name be?) or the sets i have just don't have that Icon?.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots? :)

Comment: I've uploaded the example.

Comment: [Faience icon theme](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faience-icon-theme-255099649) seems to show those icons properly for me. May be, you can check if the icon themes you use support Google Chrome?

Comment: Doesn't seem to show up, can you check which icon is it Using for you?

Comment: It looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v8iuK.png I am not sure if this is related to icon themes because those icons used by Chrome doesn't quite match my other icons.

Comment: Thanks i found it, but trying to replace the Icon doesn't seem to be working.. >.<

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2329/discussion-between-jokerdino-and-uri-herrera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Missing icons happen because Chrome/Chromium use PNG files for the MIMES. This range from 16px to 32px. The icons set in use has to have them else it won't display anything like in the screenshot.

Chrome/Chromium don't work with SVG files for the MIMES but can load SVG files for the rest of the UI components.

Comment: Uri Herrerra, Where is the index.theme file located?

Comment: Inside the Icon's folder.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.

Solved it by installing the "gnome-icon-theme-full" package.

Comment: I already had the Icons installed, and they didn't showed.

Comment: i have 3 different ubuntu installation with chrome, and all show the icons now.

Comment: Probably was/is because i use XFCE, probably not.. I've no idea

Comment: XFCE here, also solved by installing "gnome-icon-theme-full"

Comment: works like a charm :D